# Representations of determinant-one subgroup of direct product

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

View the orthogonal and special orthogonal groups $O(n)$ and $SO(n)$ either as algebraic groups over $\mathbb{C}$ or as compact Lie groups. The representations and representation rings of both are known. Consider however a direct product $\prod_iO(n_i)$ and the closed subgroup $G$ of $\prod_iO(n_i)$ consisting of elements $(g_i)_i$ such that $\prod_i\mathrm{det}g_i=1$. What is the relationship between representations of $G$, representation of $\prod_iO(n_i)$, and representations of $\prod_iSO(n_i)$?

This paper [of Segal](https://%20http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1968__34__113_0.pdf) implies that the representation ring of $G$ will be a direct product, with half as many factors as $R(\prod_iO(n_i))$, but is there really no simple explicit answer?

Comment: How uniform of an answer are you expecting? Even for just one factor there is a big difference between whether $n$ is even or odd. This the type $B$ vs type $D$ distinction in the classification of semisimple Lie algebras. Particularly relevant here is that when $n$ is odd $O(n) = SO(n) \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ because $-Id_n$ is in $O(n) - SO(n)$ and commutes with everything. When $n$ is even this central element lives in $SO(n)$ and $O(n)$ is not a direct product.

Comment: Certainly, but $R(O(2n))$ is a direct product of rings; the determinant character gives the idempotent determining the direct factors. However you are correct that neither factor is isomorphic to $R(SO(2n))$.

Comment: Modulo understanding the representations of the product of orthogonal groups, this should be a very simple version of Clifford theory, since you are asking for the relationship between representations of a group G and of a normal subgroup N with quotient group of order $2$...

Comment: ...The group of characters of $G/N$ acts on the irreducible representations of $G$ by tensor product, and the $G$-irreps come in two flavors: those that are fixed (up to isomorphism) and those in orbits of size two. The ones that are in orbits of size two remain irreducible upon restriction to $N$ (with restrictions that are isomorphic to one another), and the others split into a direct sum of two non-isomorphic representations of $N$. Moreover each irreducible representation of $N$ is one of these. There are no other isomorphisms between these.